# Tool for typing mathematical physics, e.g. differential geometry

Tags: type-theory, software-request, recommendations, programming-languages

Many expressions in mathematical physics use a rather sloppy notation, e.g. the [Lie bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) on a vector field is defined using ambiguous notation, where $X : M \rightarrow TM$ is first defined as a function on a manifold, then not applied to a $p\in M$, but to another function $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, so we have $X(z)$ either a function on a manifold , or a derivation on a function on a manifold, depending on the argument $z$.

> Each smooth vector field $X : M \rightarrow TM$ on a manifold $M$ may be regarded as a *differential operator* acting on smooth functions  $f(p)$ (where $p \in M$ and $f$ of class $C^\infty(M)$) when we define $X(f)$ to be another function whose value at a point $p$ is the *directional derivative* of $f$ at $p$ in the direction $X(p)$. In this way, each smooth vector field $X$ becomes a Derivation on $C^∞(M)$:

I am not primarily looking for a proof assistant (and have no experience in the field either), I am looking for a tool to help me understand and formalize the types of expressions to ultimately help me write better code.

There is a great book by Sussman, [Functional Differential Geometry](https://archive.org/details/FunctionalDifferentialGeometry/mode/2up), but he is more focused on implementing the actual functions in Scheme. I am looking for something similar from a type point of view, where I can also implement a few concrete function definitions.

It would be great if the tool already came with libraries for basic differential geometry.

This is already asking for too much, but are there any tools that combine types with units of measure (physical units, like kg etc.), similar to [Unitful.jl](https://painterqubits.github.io/Unitful.jl/stable/)?

Comment: A side comment: Proof assistants actually strive to make notation as sloppy as possible, because rigorous notation is tedious to write, so tons of techniques are employed — one can write a whole book about them! — to let us get away with sloppy notation. See e.g. [tag:implicit-argument]

Comment: I am starting to see this. I found an interesting paper "Elements of Differential Geometry in Lean A Report for Mathematicians" https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.00484.pdf and the notation is quite verbose to my untrained eye.